# Only with specific values matrix multiplication in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Here is the code:

```
X = [3 2 0; 5 0 7; 0 0 1];
Y = [0 0 0; 256 256 0; 256 256 0];
[row,col] = find(Y==0);
[row,col]
```

And its result:

```
ans =

     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
```

I find the 0 values in the second matrix. My question is that I want to replace (or we can multiply) other values with 0 in first matrix and gain `Z` matrix.

For example, the `Z` matrix will be:

```
Z = [0 0 0; 5 0 7; 0 0 0]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for the element-wise multiplication `X.*Y` ? If not i don't understand your question

Comment: Actually, I detect zero values in Y. Then, I want to change only zero values in X.  @obchardon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what your trying to describe is:

> Given a list of indices, say `I`, of `0`-valued elements in some matrix `Y`, construct a new matrix `Z` from a give matrix `X`, but where the set of indices `I` in `Z` are set to `0`. Limitation that `X`, `Y` and `Z` naturally have the same dimensions.

In this case, you're example is slightly off: I believe you mean that `Z` in your example should look like

```
Z =

     0     0     0
     5     0     0
     0     0     0
```

You can achieve this simply by

1. copying contents of `X` into `Z`,
2. setting indices `I` in `Z` to `0`, where `I` correspond to the set of indices with zero valued elements in `Y`.

I.e.:

```
%// example
X = [3 2 0; 5 0 7; 0 0 1];
Y = [0 0 0; 256 256 0; 256 256 0];

Z=X;            %// 1. above
Z(Y==0) = 0;    %// 2. above
```

Yielding the vector `Z` as posted above.

Comment: Nice job interpreting the question!

Comment: I am thankful! As you corrected, second row of Z should have been [5 0 0] @dfri

Comment: @LuisMendo As the exams back in the uni. days, after the exhausting task of actually understanding the questions, solving them was a less tedious task ;)

Comment: @user3470711 Happy to help!